# How to redirect user properly using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to redirect the user using this line:

```
$location.path('/edit?a='+$scope.a+'&b='+$scope.b);
```

But, doing this, I just get a new url putted into the url bar of the browser without redirection and the url contains

> localhost/dashboard/public/kol#/edit%3Fa=undefined&b=undefined

instead of

> localhost/dashboard/public/edit%3Fa=undefined&b=undefined

How to deal with this please?

Comment: did you use ng-href or href ?

Comment: @ThomasP1988, I'm doing this from the controller. Because I need to get a scope value.

Comment: @user3818045 the docemnts for `$location` are what you need to read. They explain how to do both internal app redirects as well as outside of app

Answer (score 1):

can you try it `$window.location.href` ? with injecting $window in your controller

Comment: thatt's not what you want ?

Comment: my bad...it might actually be. I am so used to thinking internal app redirect

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append search parameters to your URL. The right way to do this with angular from within js is `$location.path('/edit').search({a : $scope.a, b : $scope.b})`